# is it $http? is it $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie in AngularJS (playing with v.1.2.27). I've a simple controller like this (the html includes the .js file in its head section..duh!):

```
'use strict';

var sample = angular.module('ding', []);    
    sample.controller('sampleCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.testme = "sdsds";
        $http.get('/get/me/some/data').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.datayouwant = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });     
        });
```

The AJAX call to "/get/me/data" works and no JSONP stuff was required to make this work. And now there is piece of obvious/simple html like this:

```
   <dt ng-controller='sampleCtrl'>United States</dt>
    <dd>{{ testme }}</dd>
```

The expression testme or {{ datayouwant }} does not yield anything. I just need the values from the AJAX call to be shown here (a sort of one-way databinding). Am confused and dazed about why it does not work. I tested in chrome and FF (both latest versions). I read something about $scope.$apply() stuff but also read that $http implicitly has that call and even tried to include but FF/chrome loudly complained...

Please help me.

Comment: What do you see in the viw? errors in the console? hope u have `ng-app="ding"`

Comment: You don't need $scope.$apply here. It should work. I guess you are making some minor mistakes.

Comment: did you add `<html ng-app="ding"> ... </html>` ?

Comment: @PSL: I dont see any errors in the console and have the ng-app="ding", I've batarang and ng-inspector tools and no issues in these two either.

Comment: @Ved..Yup you are right the $scope apply isnt required.

Comment: Is the ajax call happening?  Can you see it returning data in the network tab in chrome?

Comment: @nweg yes the ajax call happily returns the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller needs to wrap `dd` as well because that needs the scope binding from the controller. currently it is applicable only to the `dt` since you have the ng-controller directive on `dt`.

Try for example:

```
  <dl ng-controller='sampleCtrl'>
    <dt >United States</dt>
    <dd>{{ testme }}</dd>
  </dl>
```

So thumb rule is that when you use ng-controller directive on any element only that element and anything inside that element (except for isolated scope directive) will have access directly or indirectly to the controller scope (prototypical inheritance). In your case what happens is angular evaluates the value of `testme` from the available scope for `dd`, if no other controllers wrap them it will be evaluated against the `$rootScope` and will just not display anything if the value for that property on that scope is not available.

And yes you are right, you do not need to perform `$scope.$apply()` after http callback is run. Angular internally will trigger a digest cycle.

**Working Code**

```js
var sample = angular.module('ding', []);
sample.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.testme = "sdsds";
  $http.get('/get/me/some/data').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.datayouwant = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ding">
  <dl ng-controller='sampleCtrl'>
    <dt>United States</dt>
    <dd>{{ testme }}</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: the fact that it is working here and does not on my system means only one thing that my system is screwing this up somehow..i need to investigate further. Thank you for your time and patience.